# Pressing enter on form submits my input text, if i add submit button it only refreshes page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I'm following a tutorial and it works perfectly fine, it submits by pressing enter. Somehow if I add a submit button it breaks it by only adding one item and replacing the last one entered. How do I make it work with both a submit button and enter?

*Here's a working example :*

https://codepen.io/sergestra/pen/WNeVEVE

**(I have placed the submit button in an html comment, uncomment to see my issue.)**

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.getElementById('item');
let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];

localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));

const liMaker = (text) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  itemsArray.push(input.value);
  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
  liMaker(input.value);
  input.value = "";
});

data.forEach(item => {
  liMaker(item);
});

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  localStorage.clear();
  while (ul.firstChild) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
  }
  itemsArray = [];
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>New Tab App</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/primitive.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="small-container">
    <h1>New Tab App</h1>

    <form>
      <input id="item" type="text" placeholder="New">
      <button>save note</button>
    </form>

    <h2>Items</h2>
    <ul></ul>

    <button>Clear All</button>
  </div>

  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A button always needs to have a `type` defined. If it has not, the default type is `submit`. That's probably your issue here. For your use case you probably want to use `type="reset"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause of your issue:**

This is because in your JavaScript there is an Event-Listener sticked to your inserted `button` (as well as to the "Clear Button"). Following part causes the removing when you click on your inserted `button`:

```
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  localStorage.clear();
  while (ul.firstChild) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
  }
  itemsArray = [];
});
```

**A way to solve it:**

You can give the "Clear button" a certain ID and reference this ID in JavaScript to stick the `click`-`function` (from above) to:

Following works for me:

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>New Tab App</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/primitive.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="small-container">
    <h1>New Tab App</h1>

    <form>
      <input id="item" type="text" placeholder="New">
       <button>save note</button>
    </form>

    <h2>Items</h2>
    <ul></ul>

    <button id="buttonClear">Clear All</button>
  </div>

  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.getElementById('item');
let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];

localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));

const liMaker = (text) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  itemsArray.push(input.value);
  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
  liMaker(input.value);
  input.value = "";
});

data.forEach(item => {
  liMaker(item);
});

clearbutton = document.getElementById("buttonClear");
clearbutton.addEventListener('click', function () {
   localStorage.clear();
   while (ul.firstChild) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
  }
  itemsArray = [];
});
```